# Setting the xpath context node in Python 3 Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I would like to perform repeated xpath searches against a certain node. How do I set this node as the context in python selenium webdriver?

```
from selenium import webdriver
d=webdriver.Chrome()
d.get("mysitehere")
d.SET(context_node) <--what goes here?
d.find_element_by_xpath("descendant::xxx[contains(text(), 'my text')]")
d.find_element_by_xpath("descendant::xxx[contains(text(), 'my other text')]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like below:

```
context = d.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@attr='value']")  # define context node

# Define descendants of context node
context.find_element_by_xpath("./descendant::xxx[contains(text(), 'my text')]")
context.find_element_by_xpath("./descendant::xxx[contains(text(), 'my other text')]")
```

Note that you need to specify dot in the beginning of XPath expression to point on context node

Comment: Also, a note to new users of xpath, to search all descendants the xxx must equal *